# Making MySQL databases readable for non-developers

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

This summer, I will be designing an e-commerce website and have chosen MySQL to organize the incredible amounts of data I will be receiving. The people I am designing for are great at making their products...but have absolutely no development or coding experience.

I have three months to make the site, and I don't begin until June. In the end, they would like an easy, readable, and preferably fasionable way to present this data. They also want to be able to manipulate it (sort by date, item, customer, etc.). They don't care if it's an Excel file, a secure webpage, or anything like that.

I know the basics of MySQL, but I am looking for ways to PRESENT the data in a way that is easy and accessible. I love to teach myself and do my own research, so my question is...what topics of interest in MySQL should I read into to learn how to present this data?

Comment: do you mean like a back office so that they can manage the application or are you talking about them looking directly at the database wit phpmyadmin for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a decent grasp of JavaScript and programming web via PHP or Java I would recommend Dojo [DataGrid](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_data_grid.html).  It is fairly simple to implement if you use the basic grid and looks and performs great.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Choose any e-commerce CMS like [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) or [oscommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) or [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/). All these e-commerce solutions has many in-built reports that would be needed by the business people..

And there are much more options available than normal reporting and these solutions covers most of the business objectives and business models , so whenever the  business evolves it will be easier to update the website with little effort..

For a list of e-commerce solutions and comparisons, visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software

Answer (score 2):

Dont use MYSQL - Oracle is going to kill it - it is in their plans - use MariaDB - (drop in replacement for MySQL)

Comment: 8 years after and MySQL still kicking and strong :)

Answer (score 2):

look into using php/mysql together with some fancy jquery stuff like dataTables to present your data. A great article/tutorial on just how to do this can be found [here ->](http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-tables-datatables-plugin-jquery-1.3-with-php)
You should get away with knowing the basics of mysql to rig something like that up to work...

If there are a lot of numeric parameters and enum type stuff, try using jquery ui to make it look nice with some sliders and fancy checkboxes etc.

I've got a prototype of something I'm working on (slowly...) that utilizes all of the above if you want to see. [here it is](http://hopedesign.info/diamondproto/)! It's for a shopping cart but you get the drift

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are building the system yourself (and don't have an off-the-shelf option)...

· If they need lots of flexibility in manipulating the data, I'd run a cron job that exports reports as CSV files for them to open in Excel.

· If there are limited views that they are interested in, I'd run the report as a php script that renders an html table, and make it sortable using a jQuery widget.